# How to set two domain names on one server?

Tags: debian, webserver, domain

I have a debian server right now that is hosting a webserver along with a couple of other services. Currently its domain is "website.com", but I want to name it also "www.website.com". I am hoping it is just a matter of adding the new subdomain to the `ddclient.conf`. And if there is no way to do this, then is there a way to somehow route "website.com" to "www.website.com" or vice versa.

My `ddclient.conf` settings are for a Dynamic DNS provider:

```
daemon=300
syslog=yes
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid
ssl=yes
protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=ipinfo.io/ip
server=domains.google.com
login=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
password=XXXXXXXXXXXX
website.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routing of the multiple names to the single server is handled by DNS. In your case it looks like you may have a dynamic IP address and you maintain the current DNS entry through Google, your DDNS provider. I would imagine that you have two choices at this point:

1. Create a CNAME record so that www.website.com points to website.com, and continue updating just website.com
2. Create a second `ddclient` entry to keep www.website.com correctly in sync with your true IP address

I'd recommend #1 myself.

The multiple domain name processing is handled by your webserver (application). You'll need to configure your Apache, Nginx, Wordpress, or whatever you use to understand the two different website names, even if one of them is simply a redirect to the other.

If Google is handling your DNS it may be possible to have it define your secondary DNS entry as a web-level redirect to the primary, thus avoiding any work on your server at all.

The server itself has just one name, which doesn't even need to correspond to any public DNS entries (but sometimes it's convenient if it matches one of them).